# Hide paragraph contents on hover with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have this code:

**HTML**

```
  <div class="image1">
        <p class="aaa">
            <h3>asdas</h3>asdsadas
        </p>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.image1{
  display: inline-block;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background: url("http://www.avocat.dac-proiect.ro/wp/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/images/images1440/b1.jpg");
  margin-left:auto;
  vertical-align:top;

}

.image1 p{ visibility: hidden;}
.image1 p:hover{ visibility: visible;}
```

Link to [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w9tx6y2z/1/)

How can I hide the section `"aaa"` and make it visible only on hover?
What is wrong with this code?

Comment: You can't put headings inside paragraphs.It's invalid HTML.

Comment: The problem is that... if you make something hidden - it isn't there to hover over. you must hover over something that is visible in order for something to happen.

Comment: As paulie said, that's the problem you have, a header inside a paragraph is so wrong in so many levels.

Comment: I think that you are looking for a tooltip, see for instance http://www.antsmagazine.com/web-development/25-examples-of-css3-and-html5-tool-tip-tutorials/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not working because you have an `h3` tag inside your `p` tag and that's not valid markup. You can always use the [Markup Validation Service](http://validator.w3.org/) to check your code.

You can remove the `h3` tag and it will work.

Also change CSS:

```
.image1 p {visibility: hidden;}
.image1:hover p {visibility: visible;}
```

See **[Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wBRvQG)**.